# React native Facebook SDK setup for Android

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I'm following the Facebook installation instructions for Android (https://github.com/facebook/react-native-fbsdk), and I'm getting a weird compilation error:

```
error: constructor FBSDKPackage in class FBSDKPackage cannot be applied to given types;
required: CallbackManager
found: no arguments
reason: actual and formal argument lists differ in length
```

My MainApplication.java:

```
@Override
    protected List<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
      return Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
          new MainReactPackage(),
          new FBSDKPackage(mCallbackManager),
          new ImagePickerPackage()
      );
    }
```

However inside build/generated/rncli/src/main/java/com/facebook/react/PackageList.java I get:

```
public ArrayList<ReactPackage> getPackages() {
    return new ArrayList<>(Arrays.<ReactPackage>asList(
      new MainReactPackage(),
      new ReactNativeFirebaseAppPackage(),new ReactNativeFirebaseAuthPackage(),new FBSDKPackage(),new RNGestureHandlerPackage(),new ImagePickerPackage()
    ));
  }
```

I've searched my code and there's definitely no instances of new FBSDKPackage() anywhere without the argument provided. I don't understand what is compiling the PackageList.java, it appears my override is not working. Also interesting to note that the compiled list includes Firebase and Gesture Handler, even though they aren't in my override array.

Also:

My /android/settings.gradle:

```
rootProject.name = 'cooky'
include ':react-native-image-picker'
project(':react-native-image-picker').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-image-picker/android')
include ':react-native-gesture-handler'
project(':react-native-gesture-handler').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-gesture-handler/android')
include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')
include ':@react-native-firebase_auth'
project(':@react-native-firebase_auth').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/auth/android')
include ':@react-native-firebase_app'
project(':@react-native-firebase_app').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/@react-native-firebase/app/android')
apply from: file("../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-android/native_modules.gradle"); applyNativeModulesSettingsGradle(settings)
```

/android/app/build.gradle dependencies:

```
dependencies {
    implementation project(':react-native-image-picker')
    implementation project(':react-native-gesture-handler')
    implementation project(':react-native-fbsdk')
    implementation project(':@react-native-firebase_auth')
    implementation project(':@react-native-firebase_app')
    implementation fileTree(dir: "libs", include: ["*.jar"])
    implementation 'com.facebook.android:facebook-android-sdk:[5,6)'
    implementation "com.facebook.react:react-native:+"  // From node_modules

    // JSC from node_modules
    if (useIntlJsc) {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc-intl:+'
    } else {
        implementation 'org.webkit:android-jsc:+'
    }
}
```

Comment: add this in your setting.gradle ``include ':react-native-fbsdk'`` and
``project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')``

Comment: I Already have `include ':react-native-fbsdk'
project(':react-native-fbsdk').projectDir = new File(rootProject.projectDir, '../node_modules/react-native-fbsdk/android')` in my /android/settings.gradle file